# BeautifulSoup causing memory leak overtime

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, memory-leaks, python-requests

I believe this topic has been popular before and still remains to be an issue.

I have now managed to create a small script which can clearly see a memory leak and that the memory will be increasing slowly overtime and, the more requests you do, the more memory will be used even though they are not in use.

Script:

```
import gc
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(
    browser={
        'browser': 'chrome',
        'mobile': True,
        'platform': 'android'
    }
)

response = scraper.get(
    'http://www.smetana.net/',
    timeout=20
)

if response.ok:
    bs4 = soup(response.text, 'lxml')

    response.close()
    bs4.decompose()
    bs4 = None
    gc.collect()
    return payload
```

and down below can you see the result:

[image: Memory]
[image: Memory2]

In the example I have given that are marked in blue, you can clearly see that after you have done a request it will be released my the memory which save us the memory usage (Also no point of having it in memory I assume?) and whenever you use the beautifulsoup. You can see that it increases 1MB. Which might not sound alot but it can be more than 1MB, sometimes 2MB which just in a longer run of script will consume lots more usage.

I have been reading lots of threads from stackoverflow with different solution such as gc.collet, bs4 = None, response.close() etc etc but as you can see nothing has been changed and the 1MB is still being in the Memory even though it will never be used after the return.

At this point I have no idea what more I can do to be able to clear the memory after a usage of Beautifulsoup. What do you guys suggest?

Comment: Maybe you can run the code that leaks memory through `subprocess` and let OS to reclaim the memory.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I dont quite get it. How would I be able to do that and how would that help?

Comment: You can run `out = subprocess.check_output(["script_that_runs_bs4", "url"])` and in `out` you have output from the script. The OS will reclaim the memory that the script allocated.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Im not sure if this will actually help but I can give it a go. Is there any information I can see with when printing out `out` ?

Comment: In `out` you have information you wanted to get from the `url` (with help of `bs4` that leaks memory). But you use `bs4` inside the `script_that_runs_bs4` and the OS will free all memory when it ends.